# Convert a string like "10s" or "10h" to Duration

Tags: java, parsing, type-conversion

I try to parse strings like mentioned in the title to Duration or something similar.
Things like `Duration.parse()` don't work the way I want it to work.

Strings like "10s" or "10h" are given. I need a solution to use that string and convert it to *something like* `Duration` or something similar.

Edit: To clarify my needs: I don't want to use "Duration-like" strings with "PTxxx" nor I want to parse those strings on my own. Somewhere out there should be a already implemented solution for that imho.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to detect 's' or 'h' inside the string and parse it using string parsing functions then convert it to your value. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 6):

[org.springframework.boot.convert.DurationStyle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/convert/DurationStyle.html) is what you are looking for.

`DurationStyle.detectAndParse("10s")`

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)? Here is how you can use `Duration.parse()`.

> Examples:
>
> ```
> "PT20.345S" -- parses as "20.345 seconds"
> "PT15M"     -- parses as "15 minutes" (where a minute is 60 seconds)
> "PT10H"     -- parses as "10 hours" (where an hour is 3600 seconds)
> "P2D"       -- parses as "2 days" (where a day is 24 hours or 86400 seconds)
> "P2DT3H4M"  -- parses as "2 days, 3 hours and 4 minutes"
> "P-6H3M"    -- parses as "-6 hours and +3 minutes"
> "-P6H3M"    -- parses as "-6 hours and -3 minutes"
> "-P-6H+3M"  -- parses as "+6 hours and -3 minutes"
> ```

So if you want a duration of 10 seconds then `Duration.parse("PT10S")` or `Duration.parse("PT10H")` for 10 hours.

Comment: Yes I know how `Duration.parse()` works.
But I don't want to use Strings like that, I only want to use "10s" etc. like used in spring boot application.yml.

Comment: Then why are you stating* Things like Duration.parse() don't work* if you know how it works?

Comment: I updated the question to avoid misunderstanding.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

```
    Duration tenSec = Duration.parse("PT10s");
    Duration tenHours = Duration.parse("PT10h");
```